# is it not allowed to query on supertype of POJO Dataset in Apache Flink Table API

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to implement a Log analyzer using Apache Flink 1.3.2 on Windows 10 with Java 1.8.0_144 IDE Eclipse Mars.

**Context:**

- There are multiple types of LogMessage.
- Creating POJO for each type.
- Creating DataSet instance of type POJO for each type.
- Then query using table API as shown below.

this works fine.

```
DataSet<String> rawLogs = env.readTextFile(input);// input is the data file path
DataSet<FirstBackupMessage> logMsgPOJODataSet = rawLogs.map(new LogMapFunction());
BatchTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env); 
Table LogMessageTable = tableEnv.fromDataSet(logMsgPOJODataSet);
Table result = tableEnv .sql("Select taskId from " + LogMessageTable);
tableEnv.toDataSet(result, Row.class).print();
```

**Requirement:**
I am trying to generalize this implementation using factory model. 
in order to do this I am trying generalize the POJO classes to LogMessage *interface*. In the above case:

```
public class FirstBackupMessage implements LogMessage
similarly 
public class SecondBackupMessage implements LogMessage
public class ThirdBackupMessage implements LogMessage
```

In the MapFunction implementation I am populating the specific class instance but output of the map function is mapped to generic reference i.e. LogMessage
in above case it would be

```
DataSet<LogMessage> logMsgPOJODataSet = rawLogs.map(new LogMapFunction());  
//the LogMapFunction.map method is populating FirstBackupMessage
```

After this if I try to query the fields present in the POJO FirstBackupMessage but now with reference to interface i.e. LogMessage
it throws the exception saying the field which I am querying is not found.

but

the strange thing is that if I print the DataSet with Generic reference i.e. logMsgPOJODataSet.print() it prints all the fields in the specific POJO in this case FirstBackupMessage.

**Question:**
is such casting to generic references into DataSet is not allowed / available in Flink Table APIs?

Comment: This is the core of OO! In Java variables have a type, and you can only access the member of that _declared type_ when dereferencing this variable. On the other hand, at runtime this variable can reference an instance of any subtype, and a method call (i.e. `toString`) is determined by this _runtime type_.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes you are right, my bad. That answers the second part why toString is printing all values. But then the question would be (or should be) how to cast it back to subtype at runtime in either flink dataset or Dayastream APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The Table API / SQL library operates on relational tables. By calling `TableEnvironment.fromDataSet(logMsgPOJODataSet)`, the `DataSet` `logMsgPOJODataSet` is logically converted into a table. During this process, the schema of the new table needs to be identified based on the type of the `logMsgPOJODataSet` `DataSet`. Flink's DataSet API uses `TypeInformation` to determine the data type of a `DataSet`.

Since the type of the `logMsgPOJODataSet` `DataSet` is `LogMessage`, the Table API does not know about any of its sub-types. Hence all fields of `LogMessage` are included, but none of the sub-type fields.

In any case, it is not possible to process rows of different types in the same table. All rows must have the same schema. Two approaches to handle the situation would be to:

1. Make the schema the superset of all sub-types and have null values for unsupported types. Maybe add another field that indicates the sub-type.
2. Add a generic `Map<String, String>` field that holds all sub-type data.

In both cases, the conversion needs to be done with the DataSet API, for example using a `MapFunction`.